# Using custom error messages for nested attributes in Laravel validator

Tags: laravel-5

I am validating a nested attribute in Laravel (5.2)

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required',
    'author.name' => 'required',
    'author.description' => 'required',
]);
```

In my custom validation language file title works, but `author.name` and `author.description` don't work.

```
'custom' => [
    'title' => [
        'required' => 'The title is required',
    ],
    'author.name' => [
        'required' => 'Name is required',
    ],
    'author.description' => [
        'required' => 'Description is required',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All attributes should be in a child array.

```
'custom' => [
    'title' => [
        'required' => 'The title is required',
    ],
    'author' => [
        'name' => [
            'required' => 'Name is required',
        ],
        'description' => [
            'required' => 'Description is required',
        ],
    ],
],
```